# How to catch multi-touch event in NSView

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsview

Is there any way to handle multi-touch in a class which extend NSView? currently 1 touch with drag event is working now.

Comment: I have a class which extend NSView, and in this class, I could catch mouseDown, mouseUp, mouseDragged events, but I don't know how to count number of touch on the screen, if it is possible, I could handle it as multi-touch event. Anybody help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but if you want your NSView subclass to accept touch events (like in iOS, touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Cancelled) and you are in OS X >= 10.6, you can put the following in your initWithFrame: method:

```
[self setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES];
[self setWantsRestingTouches:YES]; // for thumb
```

Then override the following methods:

```
- (void)touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMovedWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEndedWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelledWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event;
```

See the [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH13-SW13) for details

Comment: If possible please help me out with a problem of mine. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734940/disable-user-interaction-for-nsimageview) is the question, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am developing a feature which draw a chart and I used Core-Plot charting library, but the CPLayerHosting is extended from NSView so I don't know how to catch more than one touch points.

Very lucky for me that there are 2 CPLayerHosting class in Core-Plot project, another one is just used for IPhone and it is extended from UIView, so the problem is resolved! :)